# PHP and singletons again

Tags: php, singleton

class ConfigReader
    {
        private static $instance = NULL;
        protected $configData = array();

```
    public function getInstance()
    {
        if( self::$instance == NULL )
        {
            self::$instance == new ConfigReader();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getConfigValue( $getName )
    {
        echo 'In function';
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->configData = %READ_FROM_DATABASE%;
    }

    private function __clone() {}
}
```

And for:

```
var_dump( ConfigReader::getInstance() )
```

I got: NULL

I broke by brains... Help me, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the method getInstance, you should use only one '=' : you want to make an assignation, and not a compatison :

```
self::$instance = new ConfigReader();
```

Instead of

```
self::$instance == new ConfigReader();
```

And that method should be declared as `static`, as you are using it as a static method :

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if( self::$instance == NULL )
    {
        self::$instance = new ConfigReader();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Weth these two modifications, it should work ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Just a typo: `self::$instance == new ConfigReader()` contains == instead of =

Answer (score 5):

The method getInstance() should also be static.